# Alternative to Google Adsense content injector module

Tags: 7

I want to "float" ads in the top right of my nodes for which [Content Injector](http://drupal.org/project/adsense_injector) was nice enough in D6 moreover such ads convert well in my experience.

But for D7 is there any easy alternative? I know I can sub-theme and place the ads in appropriate positions.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be quite as versatile, but the [Block Inject](http://drupal.org/project/block_inject) module will allow you to embed adsense blocks within the node body.

Comment: It's in Alpha .. and too few sites using it. Wouldn't it be risky for production sites?

Comment: Test it, take over maintenance of Content InjectorOr or write your own. The choices are simple.

Answer (score 1):

Without a module, just type adsense1, adsense2 anywhere in content.

(it's ok for any CMS: Drupal 7, WordPress, Joomla etc.)

First, create two or many scripts in your protected /inludes folder, with lines provides by Google Adsense (or somebody else).

adsense1.inc
adsense2.inc
...
adsense99.inc

// remember: just maximum 3 adsense blocks in a webpage
// I've filtered any Flash movies

Second, edit /themes/$your_theme/page.tpl.php. Write this code replacing line

print render($page['content']);

with

if(strstr(render($page['content']),'adsense1') or strstr(render($page['content']),'adsense2')){
$pContent=explode('adsense1',render($page['content']));
$pgContent= explode('adsense2',$pContent[0]);
print $pgContent[0];
if(strstr($pContent[0],'adsense2')) include('includes/adsense2.inc');
print $pgContent[1];
if(strstr(render($page['content']),'adsense1')) include('includes/adsense1.inc');
print $pContent[1];
}else{
print render($page['content']);
}

Third, refresh portal performance.

Enjoy!

P.S. www.astralia.ro

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the easiest way to do ad's in Drupal 7 is with blocks. Then style your block. This is a tutorial on how to install google adsense VIA a simple block. It takes less then 3 minutes and takes no code skills. This is much simpler then adsense module or content injector module. Hope this helps you. My drupal username is alex_drupal_dev I made the video.  http://youtu.be/Ti6eApzJIrY